# Is sc_network safe to use for offchain gossip protocols in a parachain context?

Tags: networking, gossip

I want to leverage the Substrate peerset to build an offchain gossip protocol. This protocol will send lots of messages at the beginning of every session. Are there reasons this would be a bad idea?

We've experienced reliability issues when implementing offchain gossip protocols leveraging Substrate's networking stack specifically in a parachain environment. Does anyone know reasons why this might be? In a standalone environment our gossip system seems reliable.